# Jquery textarea .val() returning undefined unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, undefined

The following code has been working for a few weeks and has started occasionally returning 'undefined' when I use a selector in jquery to get the textarea's value, like so:

```
var text = escape($(this).find('textarea[id*=txtText]').val());
```

This control is appropriately defined below in the HTML by the following:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtText" runat="server" MaxLength="150" alt="150" TextMode="MultiLine"
     Rows="5" Columns="50" CssClass="customCss" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

I had previously accessed the text by calling the following in my jquery:

```
var text = escape($("#txtText").val());
```

But this had started returning undefined as well, which is why I changed it to the prior example. I'm confused as to why some instances of this work, and others do not.  Being a multiline textbox, could jquery be declaring it as undefined due to any

```
<br/>
```

characters that are included in the textarea?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whats `$(this)` ? Why is it an `asp:TextBox`? Such a node wouldn't be recognised as a `textarea` by jQuery...

Comment: The escape function encodes the string. It's a built in javascript function. Details can be found here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp

Comment: Is the DOM guaranteed to be fully loaded when that code runs?  If the textarea did not exist yet, val() would return undefined.

Comment: Yes. It is guaranteed to be fully loaded when it runs.  By the time this code is executed everything on the page will be loaded and the user will have already performed several actions.

Comment: Set a debugger statement and figure out what is going on. Does it find the element?

Comment: @somethinghere , using it as a textarea was from a previous solution I had found on how to recognize a multiline textbox in jquery.  I'm open to other suggestions though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're doing a `runat="server"` which makes the server change the ID. An example of this new ID could be something like `MainContent_txtText`, you can determine what the server is changing the ID to by right-clicking the textbox and clicking `Inspect` to inspect the element.

Chrome has Developer Tools built in which allows you to inspect. If you are not in Chrome, Firefox also has an Inspector, or you can download and use Firebug.

You could do a few things to circumvent this...

### Solution 1

Determine the newly-generated ID using the Inspector method in the first paragraph and access it via that ID in similar fashion to your code sample:

```
var text = escape($("#insert_id_from_inspector_here").val());
```

### Solution 2

Give the control a class, and get the value from that class element:

```
var text = escape($(".txtText").val());
```

### Solution 3

You can also print out the ID dynamically into your javascript code:

```
var text = escape($("#<%= txtText.ClientID %>").val());
```

Comment: So far this method is working - but I'd still like a further answer.  I was taught that setting ClientIDMode to static would still allow this textbox to be identified by it's ID in jquery, and usually this works for me.  Does this not apply with the type of selector I was using?

Comment: It wiil be static with ClientIDMode set to static, but that doesn't mean it won't prepend the container name(s) - it just means it won't change each time it runs.

Comment: @dave, OP has the escape function so I left it in my answer.

Comment: @sebe, I added another option which is printing out the ClientID into the javascript code. This would not require a static clientIDMode, but it means you have to use the asp statement everywhere you currently call the ID.

Comment: @sebe did my first comment answer your question about ClientIDMode?

Answer (score 0):

It could be cause on your asp:TextBox You have specified ClientIDMode of static.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtText" runat="server" MaxLength="150" alt="150" TextMode="MultiLine"
 Rows="5" Columns="50" CssClass="customCss" **ClientIDMode="Static"** />
```

If this control is contained in other controls you'd end up with something like:

ListView1_ProductIDLabel_txtText

[MSDN Details on ClientIDMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Static    The ClientID value is set to the value of the ID property. If
>   the control is a naming container, the control is used as the top of
>   the hierarchy of naming containers for any controls that it contains.

Use Chrome dev tools to look at the id from the DOM

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is...

```
var text = escape($(this).find('textarea[id*=<%=txtText.ClientID%>]').val());
```

Performance difference is negligible, even so I just usually do a view source, find w/e asp.net is calling it and use that.  The above approach is fool proof however as far as I know.